# Android Studio - NoReadAccessException

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1. Last night I came across an error message. When i place some elements into any layout I got the following error message in the Event log.

[image]

Has anybody seen this error? It says it's an intelli j error. I reinstalled it but nothing happend.

Any ideas?

Studio version: 1.5.1
Ubuntu 15.04 amd64

Comment: I had the same when editing a layout. I did have openJDK for my JDK but replaced it with Oracle's JDK (7). The error appears to have gone away. It may just be a coincidence, as I am only just attempting to migrate to AS from Eclipse. (Studio 1.5.1, Ubuntu 15.10 amd 64)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check it later.